# SSRS Export to Excel, PDF, Word Error

Tags: excel, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a SSRS report that has columns in it that when exported to Excel (XLSX). 
 It gives an error that I can't seem to figure out how to fix.

The column value is the following expression, for example:

```
=Code.GetUserDepartment(Lookup(Fields!idp.Value, Fields!ows_ID.Value,Fields!Person_ID.Value, "DataSetIdp"))
```

where

```
Public Function GetUserDepartment( personid as Integer) as String
    Dim i as Integer
    i = 0
    For i = 1 to Report.Parameters!userDepartment.Count()   
        If Report.Parameters!userDepartment.Value(i) = personid  then
            GetUserDepartment = Report.Parameters!userDepartment.Label(i)
            Exit For
        End if
    Next i
End Function
```

Another field have expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!idp.Value, Fields!ows_ID.Value,Fields!Person.Value, "DataSetIdp")
```

Where [Fields!Person] is calculated field:

```
=Right(Fields!ows_scPerson.Value,Len(Fields!ows_scPerson.Value)-(InStr(Fields!ows_scPerson.Value,"#")))
```

[The error displayed in the XLSX file is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opscz.jpg)

The value in the Excel's formula bar shows #VALUE!

Is there any way to fix this ?
The same error is displayed when exporting in PDF, CSV, DOC formats.
In the view mode, the report data is displayed correctly
[In the view mode, the report data is displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcUmT.jpg)

Comment: This may or may not be the problem but be careful how you layout your parameters and be sure to guard for null. SSRS does not adhere to short-circuit Boolean evaluation, so the right side will be evaluated in full and then compared to the left. If you are expecting the left to resolve the operation alone then you may run into trouble.

Comment: The solution was to replace all the calculated fields with their corresponding expressions.